# I need to extract the date from the middle of file name between two of the same characters in excel using a formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to pull the date from the middle of a text string. Date is between underscores and I am not sure how to grab it. this is what my code looks like right now

```
=MID(K2601,FIND("_",K2601,1)+1,FIND("_",K2601,14)-FIND("_",K2601,1)-1)
```

but it is only pulling the well name which is not what I want.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of the string you are trying to parse.  Show what it should return and what it is returning.

Comment: The string i am trying to parse is this    040303926100_541DR2-33_BELRIDGE_MIT_2022-07-22_CH_INCOMPLETE . I am trying to pull date from column k and place in column B.

Comment: Is there a pattern like *_*-*_*(date)_*_* or sth like that - otherwise it will impossible to find a formula that fits all data

Answer (score 0):

The formula would be:

```
=MID(B1,SEARCH("_????-??-??_",B1,1)+1,10)
```

What to search: B1
Find the start using pattern.
Included beginning and ending underlines to delimit. Returns the character position so add 1 to allow for beginning _.
Use Mid to extract the date starting at value returned by Search + 1 for 10 characters.

Sample run:
[image]